# How to solve this batch glitch?

Tags: batch-file

I have a little problem in my code,
if I

```
set ghot=1
```

and

```
set fo1=text
```

and try echoing

```
echo %fo%ghot%%
```

like this, it comes like

```
%fo1%
```

instead of text

Comment: FYI people are generally more willing to help if you format your post correctly and write like a grown up.

Comment: `echo !fo%ghot%!`with Delayed Expansion enabled. The "standard way" to write this _array element_ is `set fo[1]=text` and `echo !fo[%ghot%]!`. See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Answer (score 2):

I misunderstood what you were asking at first. Adding call to the line will give you the behavior you want.

```
call echo %%fo%ghot%%%
```

Edited to add the extra enclosing %'s  It works without them from the command line, but not from within a batch file.

Comment: You have to double the outer percent signs then.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative method using delayed expansion:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "ghot=1"
Set "fo1=text"
Echo=!fo%ghot%!
Timeout -1
```